# Creating a fixed footer in viewport in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create a footer fixed to the bottom of the viewport in an iOS app I'm developing (it's my first one, I come from a web dev background). However I'm having difficulty finding information on how to go about this.

What I have in mind is essentially just 3 rectangular buttons next to each other that are just constantly fixed to the bottom of the viewport. I tried dragging a toolbar into my scene as a starting point, but in the interface builder it's placing itself under my table cell, rather than fixing to the bottom. I feel like this is probably easier to do programmatically, but I just don't know where to start.

If someone could at the very least guide me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: you mean you want to set footer of UITableView ?? sorry but i can't get you exactly.. :(

Comment: Sorry, I want a footer that is constantly on the very bottom of the screen, regardless of how many table cells there are (or any other factors). If this were CSS it would be equivalent to `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`. Just always there at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... create/add custom `UIView` on your main view *`(self.view)`*

and set this custom view's `frame = (0, 0, 320 , self.view.frame.size.height - 50)` /// change value 50 to as per your requirement.

and add all of then UIControls such like textField, tableVie, button ...etc.. on this custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a UITableViewController.  Use a UIViewController, then add a table view and a toolbar.  You'll need to implement the UITableViewDelegate protocol in code and then connect the delegate in interface builder.